# Executing multiple SQL code in Pyspark SQL

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I am using python in Databricks. Is there any way to execute multiple SQL statements using spark.sql or any other method?

Answer (score 2):

For executing "multiline" sql code in pyspark-sql Use """

```
spark.sql("""  select * from db.tbl """)
```

As far as my information you cannot write "multiple" sql statement in single spark.sql() .